# Fullpage jquery navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Good day guys. I got a small question here.

kindly check this link 
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/fullpagenav_demo.html

How can I make the transition of hovering out be more smoother more like this
http://outdatedbrowser.com/

I'm a designer and know just a tiny bit about jquery but I think the smoothness can be inserted here?

```
  .mouseleave(function() {
        if (!li.find(".fpn_wrap").hasClass("fpn_clicked")) { 
          $(this).removeClass("active")
          el.recalculate(settings, width);
          el.find(".fpn_wrap").finish().css({width: "100%"})
        }
     });
```

---

here's the full code

```
    !function($){

  var defaults = {
    columns: 5,
    selector: "> li",
    hover_size: "30%",
    animateDuration: 500,
    animateFrom: "left",
    clickable: true,
    afterClicked: null
    };

    $.fn.recalculate = function(settings, width) {
      var el = $(this),
          active = false,
          total = el.find(settings.selector).length,
          last_pos = 0,
          total_width = 0;

      if(el.find(".fpn_li.active").length > 0) {

        el.find(".fpn_li.active").css({
        width: settings.hover_size
      });  


      var small_width = (100 - parseFloat(settings.hover_size))/(settings.columns - 1)

      el.find(".fpn_li:not(.active)").css({
        width: small_width + "%"
      });


        el.find(settings.selector).each(function( index, value ) {
          if ($(this).prev(".fpn_li").length > 0) {
            if($(this).prev(".fpn_li").hasClass("active")) {
              var w = settings.hover_size
            } else {
              var w = small_width
            }
          var left = total_width + parseFloat(w)

          $(this).finish().animate({
            left: left + "%"
          }, settings.animateDuration, function() {
            $(this).css({
              left: left + "%"
            });
          })

            total_width = total_width + parseFloat(w)
        }
      });
    } else {
      el.find(settings.selector).each(function( index, value ) {
        $(this).finish().animate({
          width: width + "%",
          left: (width * index) + "%"
        }, settings.animateDuration);
      });
    }

    }

    function determineDirection($el, pos){
      var w = $el.width(),
          middle = $el.offset().left + w/2;        
      return (pos.pageX > middle ? 0 : 1);
  }

  $.fn.fullpagenav = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options),
        el = $(this),
        width = 100 / settings.columns;

    el.addClass("fullpagenav").find(settings.selector).addClass("fpn_li")
    el.parent().addClass("fpn_body")


    el.find(settings.selector).each(function( index, value ) {
      var li = $(this);


      li.css({
        width: width + "%",
        left: (width * index) + "%"
      });
      li.wrapInner("<div class='fpn_wrap'></div>")

      if (settings.clickable == true && li.data("link")) {
        li.css({cursor: "pointer"}).click(function(e) {
          if (!li.find(".fpn_wrap").hasClass("fpn_clicked")) {
            li.find(".fpn_wrap > img").css({
              margin: 0,
              padding: 0,
              left: 0,
              maxHeight: "inherit"
            }).animate({
              width: "100%"
              })


            li.find(".fpn_wrap").addClass("fpn_clicked").css({position: "fixed", "z-index": 99}).finish().animate({
              width: "100%", top: 0, left: 0
            }, settings.animationDuration, function() {
              e.preventDefault()
              if (typeof settings.afterClicked == 'function') return settings.afterClicked(li.data("link"));
              window.location.href = li.data("link");
            });
          } else {
            li.find(".fpn_wrap").removeClass("fpn_clicked").finish().animate({
              width: "0%", top: 0, left: 0, height: "0%"
            }, settings.animationDuration, function() {
              $(this).attr("style","").find("> img").attr("style","")
            })
          }
        });
      }

      li.mouseenter(function(e) {
        if (!li.find(".fpn_wrap").hasClass("fpn_clicked")) {
          $(this).finish().addClass("active")
          el.recalculate(settings, width);
          if (settings.animateFrom == "auto") {

            if(determineDirection(li, e) == 1) {
              $(this).find(".fpn_wrap").finish().css({ float: "left"}).animate({width: el.find(".fpn_li.active").width()}, settings.animateDuration)
            } else {
              $(this).find(".fpn_wrap").finish().css({ float: "right"}).animate({width: el.find(".fpn_li.active").width()}, settings.animateDuration)
            }
          } else {
            $(this).find(".fpn_wrap").finish().css({ float: settings.animateFrom}).animate({width: el.find(".fpn_li.active").width()}, settings.animateDuration)
          }
        }

      }).mouseleave(function() {
        if (!li.find(".fpn_wrap").hasClass("fpn_clicked")) { 
          $(this).removeClass("active")
          el.recalculate(settings, width);
          el.find(".fpn_wrap").finish().css({width: "100%"})
        }
      });
    });

  }
}(window.jQuery);
```

Thanks : )

Comment: Alice, in comparison to JS it's much easier in css. you need a responsive grid like bootstrap, and on hover you can expand the width, its way way less pain and totally smooth.

Comment: Hello saj...can you point me to some resources or tuts perhaps? (currently searching now)...I actually thought about using css3 instead but not sure if I can achieve the effect like in this site http://outdatedbrowser.com/

Comment: greensock also has a nice optimized library. I haven't used it much since I switched to js, but the benchmarks are impressive